# barcode scanner zxing and neoreader in my app

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I have developed an android app that scans barcodes and does stuff with it. The application uses ZXing to scan the codes. However, I have found this zxing scanner very unreliable ! The percentage of the phones where it works is actually lower than the phones where it does NOT work! It only scans 1 out of 5 liner barcodes on my Xperia ARC S with 8MP on it ! And you have to give it a minute to scan it :S It worked fine on a HTC though. However I need something more reliable for my app.

I found this app NeoReader on my ARC S, and wow... it doesn't even wait for the barcode to come in the middle of the screen... It's so fast and scans every barcode I tried so far, within a second.

My question is: Can I somehow use this NeoReader to scan barcodes in my application? So far, when I needed to scan a barcode in my app, I was just calling the IntentIntegrator.java class provided by ZYing, like this:

```
     IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(Products.this);
```

which used to scan the code with their algorithms and return the barcode back to me, where I get it like this:

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            IntentResult scanResult = 
        IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (scanResult != null) {
                // Handle successful scan
                String out = scanResult.getContents();
                            }
             }
    }
```

Can I do something like this with the Neoreader, or anything that would call neoreader in the middle of my app and then make it send the barcode back to me, so that I can work with it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Sorry to hear it, but this has to be a problem in your app. Barcode Scanner is deployed on 28M devices and I have just a handful of reports of devices where it doesn't work. It most certainly doesn't fail on >50% of devices -- would that make any sense given https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android ?

Comment: can you post the NeoReader implemetation for Barcode scanning ?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself. Neoreader is not an open source app, therefore you cannot integrate it into your own app, neither you can find the source code.

About the scanning issue, seems like there's a bug in ZXing Barcode Scanner version 4.0 that makes problems on the xperia arc and arc S (and possibly other 8MP camera phones). I installed version 3.72 and it scans the barcodes just as good as the neoreader, if not even better.

Comment: (It's not a bug in Barcode Scanner, but a problem in the Xperia's implementation of Android 2.x APIs.)

Answer (score 0):

No, this will not work with NeoReader.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and called the support, whether there is an API or something like that.
It is not free, but there is a SDK which you can use in you app

http://www.neom.com/solutions/neoreader/SDK

works pretty fine.